# How to make Tomcat/Spring fail fast if it's unable to start?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm using embedded Tomcat Server. When configuring it with wrong `server.address` (IP not assigned to any interface or obviously invalid value like `123456`), I would like the embedded server (and the application) to fail fast. Instead, I get unacceptably long delay (7 seconds) before the server finally fails:

```
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:30.889000Z INFO    main:StartupInfoLogger:55   Starting CoreApplication v3.18.2 using Java 17.0.9 on e03182f0fab3 with PID 14 (/usr/local/lib/myprod/myprod-3.18.2 started by myprod in /)
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:30.894000Z DEBUG   main:StartupInfoLogger:56   Running with Spring Boot v2.7.1, Spring v5.3.21
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:32.896000Z INFO    main:TomcatWebServer:108  Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:32.993000Z DEBUG   main:ServletWebServerApplicationContext:286  Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:32.993000Z INFO    main:ServletWebServerApplicationContext:292  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2047 ms
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:33.175000Z INFO    main:LogHelper:31   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T15:27:37.828000Z WARN    main:AbstractApplicationContext:591  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
```

And that's with `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true`, without it it takes 2-3 seconds longer to fail. Is there any way to configure Spring/Tomcat to fail faster?

---

**UPD**

I was able to reduce the time between application starting and embedded server attempting to start up using lazy JPA bootstrap mode: `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy`

```
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:11.820000Z INFO    main:StartupInfoLogger:55   Starting CoreApplication v3.18.2 using Java 17.0.9 on 0554100ff86a with PID 13 (/usr/local/lib/myprod/myprod-3.18.2 started by myprod in /)
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:11.825000Z DEBUG   main:StartupInfoLogger:56   Running with Spring Boot v2.7.1, Spring v5.3.21
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:13.835000Z INFO    main:TomcatWebServer:108  Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:16.084000Z WARN    main:AbstractApplicationContext:591  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:17.574000Z WARN    task-1:JdbcEnvironmentInitiator:133  HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
...
myprod 3.18.2 2024-01-12T22:59:18.437000Z ERROR   main:SpringApplication:824  Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
```

Notice it now takes slightly over 4 seconds before embedded server throws `WebServerException`. I'm able to reproduce the gain repeatedly, and also the persistance layer logs about failed DB connection confirm that DB connection is now attempted AFTER server starts listening.

The problem is that despite the `WebServerException` application stays running for another 2.5 seconds until finally stopping. Is there any way to make it exit sooner?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the application is ready to handle the requests that it receives, the web server's HTTP connector is started at the end of the application's startup. It's at this point that the address is used and it being invalid will cause a failure.

You could bring this check forwards by manually checking that it's valid in response to the `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`. At this point, you can read `server.address` from the environment and check it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SampleTomcatApplication.class);
    app.addListeners(new ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
            String serverAddress = event.getEnvironment().getProperty("server.address");
            // Verify the address
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server address '" + serverAddress + "' is invalid");
        }

    });
    app.run(args);
}
```